# Jqgrid cannot achieve paging when use loadonce: true

Tags: jqgrid, pagination, filtering

When i use "loadonce" set to be "true",my problem is searching or filtering works ,but pagination doesn't work.If i change loadonce to be false,searchong can't work,but pagination works.

How do I make sure I set the data type to be json during the pagination alone.

```
    $grid = $("#list"),

    numberTemplate = {
        formatter: 'number',
        align: 'right',
        sorttype: 'number',
        editrules: {
            number: true,
            required: true
        },

        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']
        }
    };
var myDelOptions = {

    onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, rowid) {
        // we can use onclickSubmit function as "onclick" on "Delete" button
        // alert("The row with rowid="+rowid+" will be deleted");

        // delete row
        grid.delRowData(rowid);
        $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();

        if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
            // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
            // TODO: deleting the last row from the last page which number is higher as 1
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{
                page: grid[0].p.page
            }]);
        }

        return true;
    },
    processing: true
};

$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    keys: true
});
$grid.jqGrid({
    url: $('#contextPath').val() +"/globalcodes/getList?masterCodeSysid="+$('#Sysid').val(),        
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Sequence', 'Detail Code', 'Code Description', 'Status', 'Cross Referrences', '', ''],
    colModel: [ {
                    name: 'seqNumber',
                    width: 50,
                    editable: false,
                    search:true


                }, {
                    name: 'dtlCode',
                    width: 50,
                    editable: true,
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']}   
                }, {
                    name: 'codeDesc',
                    width: 200  ,
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']}   
                }, {
                    name: 'statusFlag',
                    width: 150,
                    edittype:"select",
                    formatter : 'select',
                    editoptions:{value:"Y:Active;N:Inactive"},
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']}   
                }, {
                    name: 'crossReferrenced',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: false,
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']}   
                },{
                    name: 'act',
                    index: 'act',
                    width: 55,
                    align: 'center',
                    search: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    formatter: 'actions',
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']}   ,
                    editable: false,
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                        onEdit: function (rowid) {
                            $('#add_detail_code').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("btnDisabled").removeClass("btnNormalInactive");
                        },
                        onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                            $grid.setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        },
                        afterSave: function (rowid) {                               
                            $('#add_detail_code').removeAttr('disabled').addClass("btnNormalInactive").removeClass("btnDisabled");
                        },
                        afterRestore: function (rowid) {                                
                            $('#add_detail_code').removeAttr('disabled').addClass("btnNormalInactive").removeClass("btnDisabled");
                        },
                        delOptions: myDelOptions
                    }
    },{
        name: 'dtlCodeSysid',
        hidden: true
    }],

    cmTemplate: {
        editable: true
    },
    jsonReader: {id:'dtlCodeSysid',
        },
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#detailCodePager',
    gridview: true,             
    ignoreCase: true,
    rowNum:10,
    rownumbers: false,
    sortname: 'col1',
    loadonce:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    height: '100%',
    deepempty: true,
    editurl: $('#contextPath').val() +"/globalcodes/saveMasterCodeDetails?masterCodeSysId="+$('#masterCodeSysid').val(),    
    //caption: 'Usage of inlineNav for inline editing',
});
$grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOperators: true
});

$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#detailCodePager', {
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    del: false,
    search:false, 
    refresh:true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't posted any code which you use, so I try to guess. Probably you implemented pagination on the server side and returns only *one page of data* in case of usage `loadonce: true` option. Correct usage of `loadonce: true` on the server side would be returning **all data**, the data need be just correctly sorted based on sorting parameters sent by jqGrid. By the way the format of returned data from the server could be just array of items instead of wrapping results in `{ "total": "xxx", "page": "yyy", "records": "zzz", "rows" : [...]}`. In case of usage `loadonce: true` option the data from `total`, `page` and `records` will be ignored and calculated based on the size of array returned data.

Comment: sorry sir, i should have posted the code for better explanation. I have now. What i have tried was i removed the rowNum:10 and tried to set"jQuery("#list").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid")" at the last line of the code ;

Comment: @user2375298: The problem is *not on the client side* - I suppose it on the server side. If you want to use `loadonce: true` option then the server have to return **all data** independent on the page size (`rowNum` option). If your server code returns only the page of data then it's wrong implementation for `loadonce: true`.

Comment: but if i remove load once as true, then the pager shows exact number of data,But when I set loadOnce:true, the pager shows the rowNum value. However i have placed the rowNum 10 in last line which resolved my pagination issue.

Comment: Thank you sir, apparently there was a restriction in the server side with number of records fetched